# Replace doubled character "YY" by one "Y" in dataset using function .replace()

Tags: python, data-cleaning

The columns below contain double YY and I need to replace them with only one Y, but I was getting error code:

```
           # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Desk'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

---

```
y_no_convert5 = ['Desk', 'Computer', 'Insurance', 'Toner']
Office_df[y_no_convert]= Office_df[y_no_convert].replace({'YY': 'Y'})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make sure to read the guidelines for posting questions. As a rule, post data associated with your code and the error that you get. Your question needs clarity. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your dataframe `Office_df` does not have `Desk` column.